# Centering images in a div vertically

Tags: jquery, image, center

I have this code for centering vertically the images in a bunch of divs.

```
function centerImages(parent, image) {
    var parent_height = $(image).parent().height();  
    var image_height = $(image).height();  
    var top_margin = (parent_height - image_height)/2;  
    $(image).css( 'margin-top' , top_margin);
}
centerImages(".clients li", ".clients li img");
```

.. but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Could you post the relevant HTML as well please

Comment: does your div have all the same height and contain only the image? in that case you could achieve the same behaviour in pure css

Comment: @F.Calderan Yes, they do. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead...

```
function centerImages(image) {
    var parent_height = $(image).parent().height();  
    var image_height = $(image).height();  
    var top_margin = (parent_height - image_height) / 2;  
    $(image).css( 'margin-top' , top_margin);
}
$(".clients li img").each(function() {
    centerImages(this);
});
```

You weren't actually passing in images, just the class selector.  The above selects all relevant images and passes them in - there's no need for the parent parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Try to this one,

```
div.clients li img { vertical-align:middle; }
```

Comment: this rule alone won't work if the parent's `line-height` is not equal to its `height`.

Answer (score 1):

if your `div` have all the same height and contain only the image, that's a pure CSS solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/Tpy2w/

Relevant CSS

```
div {
  width: 300px;
  height : 300px; 
  line-height: 300px; 
  text-align: center;    
}

div img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Just set an `height` and the same `line-height` for the div. Then apply `vertical-align: middle` on the image

Comment: Like it should be :) Even when the parent height is not always the same I prefer just altering the height and lineheight for the parent with JS.

Comment: yes, it's preferable because it will make unnecessary to also calculate and change the `margin-top` of the image via js